# TypeError: function() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator

Tags: python, typeerror

While trying to write a tiny, obfuscated type checker, an unacceptable code pattern was discovered. However, it inconsistently fails to work properly. This is the code that was initally written to test it with.

```
def statictypes(a):
    def b(a, b, c):
        if b in a and not isinstance(c, a[b]): raise TypeError('{} should be {}, not {}'.format(b, a[b], type(c)))
        return c
    return __import__('functools').wraps(a)(lambda *c: b(a.__annotations__, 'return', a(*(b(a.__annotations__, *d) for d in zip(a.__code__.co_varnames, c)))))

@statictypes
def isallinstance(iterable: object, class_or_type_or_tuple: (type, tuple)) -> bool:
    """isallinstance(iterable, class_or_type_or_tuple) -> bool

    Return whether all items in an iterable are instances of a class or of a
    subclass thereof. With a type as second argument, return whether that is
    all items' type. The form using a tuple, isallinstance(x, (A, B, ...)),
    is a shortcut for any(isallinstance(x, y) for y in (A, B, ...)).
    """
    return all(isinstance(item, class_or_type_or_tuple) for item in iterable)
```

The following shows a conversation with Python's interpreter and highlights the error that comes up. A `TypeError` is generated, but not the one that was expected. While generators were fine, now they fail.

```
>>> isallinstance(range(1000000), int)
True
>>> isallinstance(range(1000000), (int, float))
True
>>> isallinstance(range(1000000), [int, float])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    isallinstance(range(1000000), [int, float])
  File "C:\Users\schappell\Downloads\test.py", line 5, in <lambda>
    return __import__('functools').wraps(a)(lambda *c: b(a.__annotations__, 'return', a(*(b(a.__annotations__, *d) for d in zip(a.__code__.co_varnames, c)))))
TypeError: isallinstance() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator
```

The `statictypes` function can be rewritten, and the `isallinstance` function redefined and wrapped. The simplest solution is to rewrite  the generatior in `statictypes` to be a list comprehension.

```
def statictypes(a):
    def b(a, b, c):
        if b in a and not isinstance(c, a[b]): raise TypeError('{} should be {}, not {}'.format(b, a[b], type(c)))
        return c
    return __import__('functools').wraps(a)(lambda *c: b(a.__annotations__, 'return', a(*[b(a.__annotations__, *d) for d in zip(a.__code__.co_varnames, c)])))
```

After that, the `isallinstance` will starting working as expected once it is recreated from scratch. The `TypeError` stating what was wrong with the second argument is properly generated as was desired.

```
>>> isallinstance(range(1000000), int)
True
>>> isallinstance(range(1000000), (int, float))
True
>>> isallinstance(range(1000000), [int, float])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    isallinstance(range(1000000), [int, float])
  File "C:\Users\schappell\Downloads\test.py", line 5, in <lambda>
    return __import__('functools').wraps(a)(lambda *c: b(a.__annotations__, 'return', a(*[b(a.__annotations__, *d) for d in zip(a.__code__.co_varnames, c)])))
  File "C:\Users\schappell\Downloads\test.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
    return __import__('functools').wraps(a)(lambda *c: b(a.__annotations__, 'return', a(*[b(a.__annotations__, *d) for d in zip(a.__code__.co_varnames, c)])))
  File "C:\Users\schappell\Downloads\test.py", line 3, in b
    if b in a and not isinstance(c, a[b]): raise TypeError('{} should be {}, not {}'.format(b, a[b], type(c)))
TypeError: class_or_type_or_tuple should be (<class 'type'>, <class 'tuple'>), not <class 'list'>
```

**Questions:**

1. Why does the first function with the generator somtimes work and other times fail?
2. Why is a generator not considered a sequence (since it generates a sequence)?
3. Why is a sequence needed when a generator obviously works some of the time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Because `isinstance`, like a couple of other screwy standard library functions, does a different thing when you give it a tuple than other sequences. Namely, it works, and checks that the type is any of the ones given.
2. Because it isn't. See the [sequence protocol definition](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes). It'd need to implement `__getitem__` to be one.
3. A bug, which still [hasn't been merged](http://bugs.python.org/issue4806), which is telling you that your generator is broken, but with the incorrect error message.

Also, please don't dirty our lovely language with type checking like this for anything but good reasons :).

Comment: Ad 1.: Look at the line the error occurs in – there is no `isinstance()` call in that line.

Comment: OK, I see – the error is reported in the wrong line, due to the bug mentioned in 3.

Comment: I've been working with Python for about 6 years and do not need type checking. This was just an experiment to see how small a functional type-checker could be made. Hardly anyone appears to be taking advantage of function annotations, and this seemed like a creative way to use them.

Comment: Ah! Cool, well, hope it works now then :)? You can add a call to `tuple()` or make sure your caller is always told to pass in a `tuple`.

Comment: Replacing the generator expression with a list comprehension worked well enough. Alternatively, the generator expression could have had `tuple` prefixing it. Thanks for the explanation! Do you think the bug will be fixed soon? The patch appears to need reviewing.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anyone championing it at the moment, no. I don't have any insider info :). But it is a kind of annoying bug, if you're up for it, bugging a core developer to review the patch would probably move it further.