# Whether or not to force type checking for python

Tags: python, dynamic-typing, semantics

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493159/chould-i-force-python-type-checking) and was told to cross post here.

I recently moved to python after being stuck in a rut called java.

But perhaps as a remnant of my days with a strongly typed language I often find myself writing functions and then forcing type checks. For example:

```
def orSearch(d, query):
    assert (type(d) == dict)
    assert (type(query) == list)
```

Should I keep doing this? what are the advantages to doing/not doing this?

I'm aware that the assert statement increases the number of function calls. Let's assume that's negligible. What is it semantically that I can do to enforce type checking? How would the try/except statement help or hurt?