# When should I use type checking (if ever) in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic-typing

I'm starting to learn Python and as a primarily Java developer the biggest issue I am having is understanding when and when not to use type checking. Most people seem to be saying that Python code shouldn't need type checking, but there are many cases when I believe it is necessary. For example, let's say I need to use a method parameter to perform an arithmetic operation, why shouldn't I make sure the argument is a numeric data type?

This issue is not only limited to functions. The same thought process occurs to me for class variables. Why and when should I or shouldn't I use properties (using `@property`) to check type instead of regularly implemented class variables?

This is a new way of approaching development for me so I would appreciate help understanding.

Comment: Why *should* you check that your method is receivng a numeric type? If it doesn't, all you can do is raise some kind of exception; but an exception would *already* be raised if you tried to do an arithmetic operation on a type that doesn't support it. So what's the point of checking explicitly?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950386/is-it-pythonic-to-check-function-argument-types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I force Python type checking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493159/should-i-force-python-type-checking)

Comment: @gerosalesc that answer focuses more on **why** you **shouldn't** do it in general. I'm looking more for specifically **when** (if ever) you **should**.

Answer (score 6):

It's not *Pythonic* to check type info, use duck typing instead: if it *looks* like a duck, *walks* like a duck and *quacks* like a duck then it *is* a duck.

```
def quack(duck):
    duck.quack()
```

this will only run if `duck` has a callable `quack` attrubute, it will raise an exception otherwise which can be caught by the caller.

Comment: Just for the record, some background for the term duck-typing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing

Comment: The problem typically is that you ask it to quack only when the user frobs the widget in that particular way, and so you discover that somebody passed a Dog instead of a Duck only during the most important demo ever.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is probably start without any typechecking and see what happens. You'll probably find out - as I did 17 years ago and much to my surprise - that you need it *way*  less than you believe. For the record  used to think you couldn't hope to write anything but quick scripts and toy programs without strict typechecking and lost a lot of time fighting against the language until I started  reading serious python apps code and the stdlib code and found out it just worked without.