# How to include condition in composite list comprehension?

Tags: python

I would like to flatten a list but keep `NaN`s. The following base code works when there are no `NaN`s:

```
l = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5]]
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now if I have the following case it will break:

```
import numpy as np
l = [[1], [2, 3, 4], np.nan, [5]]
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

which makes sense, but I need this border case to be handled and I'm not sure how to add the special case condition in the list comprehension above. How can I modify such comprehension to cover such case?

The expected output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check to see if the sublist is iterable. If not then wrap it in a tuple to then be flattened:

```py
import numpy as np

l = [[1], [2, 3, 4], np.nan, [5]]

[item for sublist in l for item in (sublist if hasattr(sublist, "__iter__") else [sublist])]

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, nan, 5]
```

Using `chain` from `itertools` would make it a bit cleaner:

```py
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*(sublist if hasattr(sublist, "__iter__") else (sublist, ) for sublist in l)))
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, nan, 5]
```

[*Source for checking if iterable (StackOverflow)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable)

Answer (score 1):

Trying different things I found a possible solution:

```
[item for sublist in l for item in (sublist if type(sublist)==list else [sublist])]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 5]
```

Comment: Typechecking is never a good approach, you can instead use `isinstance` builtin, more details at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493159/should-i-force-python-type-checking